# How do encode a string as 8-bit ASCII characters?

Tags: java, c++, ascii

I am trying to connect to a server that another developer created. He is no longer available, so I am trying to interpret what he is meaning.

I am creating a UDP message to send to the server, and in the description for one of the required fields for the message he has this:

> A name for the Client, encoded using 8-bit ASCII characters

For example, if I wanted to use the name "MyName", the result would be (char, dec, hex):

```
| M |  77 | 0x4D |
| y | 121 | 0x79 |
| N |  78 | 0x4E |
| a |  97 | 0x61 |
| m | 109 | 0x6D |
| e | 101 | 0x65 |
```

I am just a little confused as to what should be in the field. Should it be

```
0771217897109101
```

Or should it be

```
0x4D0x790x4E0x610x6D0x65
```

Or should it be something completely different?

As an FYI, He wrote the server using C++ and I am using Java. I know that doesn't make a difference, I just thought I would add that bit of info.

Comment: With `byte[] b = { 0x4D, 0x79, 0x4E...};` or `byte[]b = { 077, 0121, 078...}`. Trap: Java chars are 16 bits Unicode encoded, while C++ chars commonly are 8 bits.

Comment: Where is the protocol description? The description itself makes no sense; what if the client's name is "äïëöü", where none of the characters can be encoded in ASCII?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Very cool ... thank you so much, sir!

Comment: @fge His documentation says we cannot use non-printable characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this involves 3rd party code we do not have access to, so it is impossible to comment on

Comment: I would suggest creating a map `map<char,byte>` that holds your java 16-bit char mapped to its ASCII counterpart. Build a string and then loop through your map to build a byte string. However, I am sure the JavaString class has something built into it to get you this data since 8-bit chars are so common.

Comment: Number is the same no matter if you use hexadecimal, decimal, binary, octal or whatever base to write that number down. When you decode the message you read byte by byte. Knowing that these bytes are meant to represent ASCII characters is just matter of interpretation. The same story when creating message, you write byte that you know means some character, for someone not knowing that, that's some meaningles stream of bits.

Comment: @Freddy I will look into that as well. Thank you.

Comment: ASCII is well-defined. It's pretty restrictive but well-defined. On the other hand you need to know if the field should be null-terminated or padded with spaces or have a length prefixed or what.

Comment: @Brian aren't the characters fge gave printable ?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is supposed to be 50 characters max, and padded with 0s.

Comment: @ControlAltDel So, where is a person supposed to go if he/she has questions like this?

Comment: @Brian Ignore the elitist of SO. Your question is fine and it takes more then one oppressor to close your question. Remember the push people around crowd from the Sun Java developer forums needed somewhere to go and push people around w/ their superior intellect.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Why? His problem is clear, he has a protocol specification and want to know how to manage this in Java. Why would you need server code?

Comment: @Freddy @Brian `byte [] b = "MyName".getBytes();` is generally sufficient (provided the default char encoding is adequate).

Comment: Look, if the answer is just the trivial String.getBytes(), that's excellent - problem solved. Brian's inclusion of a whole encoding table made me think that the binary needed to be encoded as either a decimal or a hexidecimal string ("0771217897109101" or "0x4D0x790x4E0x610x6D0x65"), and if that was the case, there's no way to comment on which of these is correct. But the SO closing system works well as even though I seem to have misinterpreted the question, others seem to be helping to solve it.

Comment: Oh, so "ä" is not a printable character?

Comment: @fge: `ä` is a printable character, but it is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Do you have a complete character table?  Any documentation to tell you whether the 8-bit encoding is ISO Latin-1, Latin-15, Windows-1252, or UTF-8?  Can you transmit `€`, and if so, how is it encoded?

Comment: @RemyLebeau and? This is 2015; ASCII is long dead

Comment: @fge: I know that. YOU asked a question about `ä`, I answered it.  The OP's question asked about ASCII.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and you don't seem to understand the full extent of the problem at hand -- misdefinition. But I do.

Comment: How about [protocoll buffers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Java:

```
String name = ...; // "MyName", etc
byte[] arr = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
// append arr to UDP message as needed...
```

There is no such thing as **8bit** ASCII.  ASCII is only **7bit**.  Character values outside of the valid ASCII range (0-127) will be converted to `?` (hex 0x3F).  Characters in the 128-255 range are commonly referred to as ANSI or Extended ASCII.  These are locale-specific characters.  If the server actually expects *8bit* characters, then it is not expecting ASCII, it is expecting ANSI instead, which leads to language conflicts when using non-ASCII characters.  Most modern servers typically expect UTF-8 where 8bit character data is allowed.  You will have to refer to this server's documentation or source code to figure out what it actually expects.  It sounds like it might actually expect 7bit ASCII characters that are simply extended to 8bit bytes (so no characters > 127 allowed).

Comment: Maybe with an added `"\r\n"` (CR+LF newline) or `"\u0000"` (C string terminator).

Comment: @JoopEggen: That statement does not apply to this discussion, or my answer. The question was about putting an ASCII string into a UDP message. How the UDP message delimits its fields depends on the particular UDP protocol being implemented.

Comment: It should be noted that this method will only create a `CharsetEncoder` which will replace potential unmappable characters (see `CodingErrorAction`)

Comment: @fge: That goes back to my statement about "*Character values outside of the valid ASCII range (0-127) will be converted to `?` (hex 0x3F).*"  The OP's spec mentions ASCII.  This is how to convert a `String` to ASCII in Java. If the server in question can support other 8bit charsets, then simply change the parameter value of `getBytes()` accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "That goes back to my statement about "Character values outside of the valid ASCII range" <-- no it doesn't. Take EBCDIC as an example. It just happens that the Unicode standard defined code points so as to be backwards compatible with ASCII, and even some ISO charsets, where possible. The problem here is that the OP's specification is awfully misguided _and_ misguiding.

Comment: @fge: a Java `String` is implemented internally using Unicode codepoints in UTF-16 format (although that format may be changing in the next major Java release). EBCDIC is a character byte encoding, it does not apply to this situation. Calling `getBytes()` on a `String` converts its internal Unicode codepoint values to the specified byte encoding. When I said "character values", I was referring to the codepoints that the `String` represents. So, `String` characters above U+007F are not supported by ASCII and will be encoded as byte 0x3F by `getBytes(US_ASCII)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it _does_ apply. .getBytes() applies a _character encoding_. And with EBCDIC, well, your ASCII 'a' is not EBCDIC's 'a', for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95501/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-fge).